# sparse binary vector

Tags: sparse-matrices

I want to know if the following problem has been solved

max_w w'Rw

where the entries of the vector w are binary (w_i= {0,1} )

Comment: where the matrix is positive semidefinite. Obviously, this problem is a NP-Hard combinatorial problem. My question is if this problem can be relaxed and somehow rewritten as a convex problem.

Thanks

Comment: The statement of the question should be edited into the body of the question, not left in a comment. 

Comment: search for "binary QP" or "boolean QP" and you'll find tons of info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- After a Cholesky factorization $R=T'T$, your problem becomes the maximization of the Euclidean norm over the parallelotope formed by the points $Tw$. This problem is discussed in
  H. L. Bodlaender,    P. Gritzmann,    V. Klee,    J. van Leeuwen:
  [Computational complexity of norm-maximization](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%252FBF02123011), Combinatorica **10**
  (1990), 203-225.
- If your matrix is just symmetric, not necessarily p.s.d., then it is essentially the maximum cut problem. For this problem, there are (famous) convex relaxations, using for example semidefinite programming.